# How do you organize your output for a project?

Tags: r, biostatistics, presentation

When you are performing your analyses, how do you keep your results organized?

Do you keep a parallel word document and copy/paste the result as you build your 'story'?

Was curious to see how other researchers and statisticians organize their workflows.

Comment: https://github.com/

Comment: I'm talking about your own academic analyses for projects - i.e. completing a biomedical project that will result in a submission to a journal.

Comment: yeah, I am too.

Comment: I tool the liberty of editing out the phrase "in `r`" in order to make your question on topic here rather than appearing to focus on one particular computing environment.

Comment: Isn't Github structured for software development?

Comment: GitHub is structured for sharing and modifying documents of all sorts.

Comment: Given that this is CW, I think we could consider this worth keeping open. I suspect this is a worthwhile topic that will be of value to many people.

Answer (score 4):

A really nice way to keep your results organized is to use rmarkdown.  It interweaves human language and presentation with the r programming language.  So at the end you have a presentable document that runs and presents the results of r code along the way.

It a combination of markdown and r code so that you both have runnable code and a structure to present the results of your code.  Markdown is simple syntax that allows you to build simple webpages (or other kinds of documents) from text.  Markdown is to html like latex is to pdf. So rmarkdown just adds the functionality of displaying the results of r code as well in the flow of the document.

I usually don't write the final paper in rmarkdown but it is nice starting place for how I want to present the experimental section or if I want to highlight certain results on my webpage.

Here are some resources:

1. [rmarkdown cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf)
2. [official website](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/)
3. [long rmarkdown example](https://gist.github.com/jeromyanglim/2716336)

Comment: Markdown looks interesting. Playing devil's advocate, wouldn't it be easier to just copy/paste right into a word processor, though? You have to code the syntax to get the formatting you want which adds some time I would think.

Comment: @MattCrow It is true that markdown doesn't have as much control over format as Word (at least if you don't learn any advanced tools). However, rmarkdown provides a simple way to present both human thoughts and machine output in a way that **is easy to change both**.  How many times have you had to change all your graphs just a little?  Or maybe the output of your code? Then in that case copying and pasting is a big time waster and frustrating.

Comment: Markdown is great. I use Jupyter Notebook a lot and cells can be markdown or code cells.